# Update nested object based on "name" field

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB, so forgive my ignorance.Suppose you have the document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
"google" : { "googleId" : ..., "username" : "Johnny",  
"followers" : [ { name:"niklas", email:"niklas@hotmail.com" } ] }, 
"__v" : 0 }
```

When admin "Johny" obtains a new follower, i can add him using

```
       User.update(query,
         {$addToSet:{google.followers:{name:"Maria" , email:"Maria@hotmail.com"}}},
         {upsert:true,new:true}...
```

My problem occurs when "niklas" changes his email. Using $addToSet simply adds a new object. How can i update the existing email of "niklas" or add it if there is no such entry;
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you have no idea about the purpose of documents! How can you put a variable as field name? `{ "niklas":"niklas@hotmail.com" }` Yes, you can insert everything, but you will struggle when you start retrieving data or when you want to do CRUD based on conditions/grouping. Go with a structure like: `"followers" : [ {name:"niklas", email:"niklas@hotmail.com"},...]`

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. I edited my structure as you propose and the question remains

Answer (score 0):

To update existing email of "niklas", you can the positional "$" operator. Something like:

```
    db.User.update(
        {"followers.name" : "niklasaa"},
       {$set: {"followers.$.email": "new-email"}}
    )
```